# Windows listing of files from command line

Tags: windows

In Windows I want to list the files from the drive in all the subfolders with the following attributes

- From all the subfolders
- File name
- File Creation date
- File Last Modified date
- User name of last modifier of the file

I use the following command:

```
DIR /S /O:NS /T:CAW
```

and

```
/s gives all files in subfolders
/O:N gives name
/O:S gives file size

/T:C gives creation time
/T:W gives last modified time
```

My questions:

1. Is this the correct way to use the command?
2. How should I get the user name who modified/created the content last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOS command looks correct. However I use something like the following command and output my results to a text file so I can then review and use it:

```
dir "%windir%\*.*" /a:-d /o:ns /t:ca /s >files.txt
```

I also like to insert the `/b` switch however no timefield info will display.

Change the filter `<path>\*.*` if you like including the full path &/or from the current directory to be something more specific.

Comment: Thanks - How should I get the suer name who last modified the file